# Arrow cursor hotspot off by a few pixels

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad

On my MacBook Pro i have realised that the default mouse cursor (black arrow) has its hotspot a few pixels off the top left corner. It becomes obvious if I move the cursor slowly to a button in the browser. While the tip of the arrow is already like 3 or 4 pixels in the button it does not highlight it yet. When I move it one pixel further the cursor turns to the hand cursor and the tip of the finger is exactly on the edge of the button.

Is this on purpose? Can I change that somewhere?

Comment: The "Tags" link just above the question here for example. I move the cursor slowly from the bottom there, suddenly the "Tags" highlights and the cursor becomes the hand cursor and jumps down several pixels to the bottom line of the highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

After closer inspection I figured out that the white border of the arrow cursor is not considered part of the cursor, only the black part is, then it seems pixel perfect. It is very confusing to me but I guess its working as intended.